# How to delete only selected rows from DB after printed them in foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

I'm wondering how I can delete selected (with checkbox) rows from a database that were printed using the foreach loop.
For now I only have this:

```
 if(isset($_POST['submitS1'])) {
        $myads = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM ads ORDER BY id DESC");
        foreach ($myads as $pointer2) {
            $id_ad = $pointer2->id;
          $title = $pointer2->title;
          $text1 = $pointer2->text1;
          $nme = $pointer2->name;
          echo '<br><h2>Message:</h2>'.$text1.'';
          echo '<br><h2>Title:</h2>'.$title.'<br>';
          echo '<br><h2>Name:</h2>'.$name.'<br>';
         echo ' <form method="post"><input type="checkbox" name="accept" value="accepto">Delete this ad<br>
        </form>';


        }
 echo '<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="submito" value="Delete selected ads">
        </form>';
        if(isset($_POST['submito'], $_POST['accept'])) {
        $sql2 ="DELETE FROM `mydb`.`ads` WHERE `ads`.`id` = ".$id_ad."";
        $wpdb->query($sql2);
        }

        }
```

Comment: you've an out of scope issue; use one form, not two with a hidden input for the said row(s). Plus, you need to use those checkboxes as an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use only one form.

Set your checkbox names to be "delete_ids[$id]"

```
<input type="checkbox" name="delete_ids[<?php echo $id;?>]" />
```

PHP will process the POST data and give you a neat POST variable called delete_ids which contains an array of the ids you need to delete (as keys). Iterate over it... and delete.

```
$ids = array_keys( $_POST["delete_ids"] );
if(count( $ids ))
{
    var_dump( $ids );
    $ids = implode( ",", array_map( intval, $ids ));
    $sql = "DELETE FROM... WHERE id IN ($ids)";
    .....
```

Simple as that.